# Can we map a few random points on a plane to that of a regular polygon using some relation or transformation?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, graph-theory, transformation, polygons

Before I begin, I must confess: I myself don't know what am I looking for over here. Please bear with me.

I am looking forward to knowing if I can find a *symmetry* out of some seemingly random points on a plane? I want to *map* or *transform* them to some regular polygon so that I can study the properties of the configuration.

Actually, this question has borne out of my ongoing research which belongs to the domain of Physics. The *propeties* that I'd talked about, pertains to the physical properties. I believe my question belongs to the domain of Graph Theory or is it Topology?

Any experts? Thanks.

Comment: you can always map 4 distinct points in the plane to $(0, \pm1)$ and $(\pm 1, 0$, for example, but what will that give you?

Comment: Oh really? We can map any four random points to that of a square? Pls shed some light on this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry @gt6989b but I cannot currently disclose how it will help me.

Answer (score 1):

Given a set of any 4 points $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^4$ you can define
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
(-1,0), & (x,y) = (x_1,y_1)\\
(1,0), & (x,y) = (x_2,y_2)\\
(0,-1), & (x,y) = (x_3,y_3)\\
(0,1), & (x,y) = (x_4,y_4)\\
(x,y)   & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
which satisfies the condition you wrote in the question.

Comment: Hmm, what if there is a point in the set which is also the vertex of the square, such as $(1,0)$. Then won't it become a many-one mapping?

Comment: @Vibhu sure, and it is quite likely discontinuous also, but you did not list that as a requirement in the question -- this answers the vague problem with no context you posted...

Comment: I agree with you. The question is just as vague to me as it is to you.